# How to disable Sci-Hub display of PDF

Tags: pdf, sci-hub

I frequently use Sci-Hub. However, I would like Sci-Hub to **not** display PDFs in my browser. Apparently the site uses some kind of JavaScript to create a PDF viewer, as my browser is set to never display PDFs.

I would simply like to access the download link for PDFs on Sci-Hub without the in-browser display. Is there some way to accomplish this with uBlock Origin, or NoScript or similar?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I agree that this PDF view that they have implemented lately is really annoying.

Comment: @HermanToothrot Alas no.